# Persistent download notification on Galaxy S3 running Android 4.3

Tags: notifications, samsung, downloading, bugs

My Galaxy S3 from Sprint keeps showing me that a file (a picture) has been downloaded. I deleted the downloaded file after a day or two, yet the notification still pops up and when I tap on it, it says *item not found*.  I believe there is a bug in the software that this keeps happening. How can I get rid of this?

*Note*: **I don't want** to get rid of download notifications at all, just this one.

Answer (score 6):

Saw this on another site:

Ryan answered 4 weeks ago
I was having the same issue after I updated my Galaxy S3 to Android 4.3.
I think I just fixed it. Here's what I did:

- From the home screen, click the Apps icon
- Open the "Downloads" app
- In my case the files that kept showing up in the notification pull down were in the Other Downloads tab
- Click the "Clear list" button at the bottom of the screen

After a restart I didn't get any more notifications.

*Source: Just did this myself.*